# Application of Holder's Inequality

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ has ﬁnite variance, $Y$ is normally distributed. $X$, $Y$ may not be
independent. We denote $Z = XY$ .
Show that $E|Z|^n < \infty$ for all $1 \le n < 2$;

---

I tried writing down Holder's inequality and seeing how it could be applied to this, but I am stuck at the fact that $X$ and $Y$ may not be independent.

Comment: Independence has nothing to do with Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Independence is irrelevant, this is a real analysis problem much more than a probability one.

Let $f$ be the probability density function of $X$ and $g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ be the pdf of $Y$.

We need to prove that $||(fg)^n||<\infty$ given that $||f||_2<\infty$.

Hölder's inequality tells us that 
$$||(fg)^n||_1\le ||f^n||_p\cdot||g^n||_q = ||f^{np}||_1\cdot||g^{nq}||_1$$
when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

Let $np=2$, then $p>1$ and we get 
$$||(fg)^n||_1\le ||f^2||_1\cdot||g^{nq}||_1 <\infty$$
 because $||g||_a<\infty$ for all $a=nq$ and $||f^2||_1=||f||_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a question of analysis. Then, I will use the integral notation instead of the expectation notation ($ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_\Omega X d\mathbb{P}$)

Ok... We will apply Hölder's inequality on the functions $|X|^n$ and $|Y|^n$ for $ 1\le n < 2$. So we need to know if $\int|X|^{np} $ and $\int|Y|^{nq}$ are both finite for some choice of $p$ and $q$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$, right?

But, for a moment, forget Hölder's and look only to $\int|X|^{np}$. You can do the follow

$$\int|X|^{np} = \int_{|X|\le1} |X|^{np} + \int_{|X| >1} |X|^{np}$$
(This kind of separation is useful trick)

The first integral on the right side is less than $P(|X| \le 1)$. For other integral, note that if $np \le 2$ you will have $$\int_{|X| >1}|X|^{np} \le \int_{|X| >1} |X|^2$$ and $\int_{|X| >1} |X|^2$ is finite by hypothesis. This is true if $p \le \frac{2}{n}$.

You can apply the same argument to $Y$ since it has finite second moment.

Now you have to show that there's a solution for the equation $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ inside the square $(0,\frac{2}{n}]\times(0,\frac{2}{n}]$. But this is very reasonable once the continuos function $g(p,q)=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$ tends to infinite when $p$ and $q$ approach to zero.